# How to add more button in XCode 4?

Tags: iphone, xcode4, uitabbarcontroller

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046686/how-to-add-more-button-to-tab-bar) about adding a 'more' button to the tab bar. It says if we add a 5th button, the tab bar controller will automatically add a 'more' button. But, in XCode 4 , adding a new tab to the tab bar is different and so it *doesn't* take the 5th button as a 'more' button'.

What  do I have to do to add a 'more' button to the tab bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'More' button will only appear after you have added a 6th tab bar item.

Answer (score 0):

on tabbar you can add 8 button after that it will show 7 tabbar button and "More" tab in which other tab will show in tabular format. You can edit it.