# Tab Bar & tab bar items in UIViewController

Tags: ios, tabbar, uitabbaritem

I added Tab Bar and a 6 or 7 tab bar items on it by dragging them to a UIViewController , and then add a web view above .

My goal is to load a different local HTML files in web view when clicking different tab 
I make the Tab Bar as a delegate for the UIViewController and then used this method to implement action of each tab .

My problem is when I add 6 or 7 tabs They appeared side by side and the "more" button DONT work !! How can I activate this "more" tab ??

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{
    if(item.tag == 1)
    {

        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        webview.opaque = NO;
        webview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [webview loadRequest:request];

    }
}
```

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046686/how-to-add-more-button-to-tab-bar

Comment: I tried to do that before and nothing changed !! the 7 tab bar items appear side by side .

Comment: can you include the code where you add the Viewcontrollers into the tab

Comment: No code .. I just drag and drop Tabbar and Tabbar items on the UIViewController in storyboard.